# Flipping UIViews From Top / Bottom

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, transition

I'm well aware that there are only two available UIView transitions, UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft and UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight.  I'm wondering if there is anyway that I can implement / emulate a UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromTop or UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromBottom.

The only way I can think to do this is by flipping the x axis with the y axis, but I've not seen any information about how to do this.  Just setting the coordinates of each axis won't fix the issue as the x-axis till remains the x-axis.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I've posted answer for flipFromBottom that worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144446/uiview-flip-vertical-animation/7463047#7463047

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by applying a CATransform3D to your main view's CALayer, with your secondary view's CALayer behind it.  In [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372018/widget-flip-behavior-in-core-animation-cocoa/372419#372419), I point to a Mac implementation of this animation by Mike Lee.  You should be able to reuse a significant portion of that code to recreate this effect on the iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Guess you'll have to use a UIView animation block with a 3D rotation transform of 90 degrees, have the Core Animation delegate call you when that's done, swap the view with the new one (3D rotated on the other side) and chain with the last 90 degrees for the new view...

Answer (score 1):

Although its not exactly what you want, there are two built-in animations that you didn't mention:  UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown and UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp.

CurlUp looks like someone is peeling the view from the bottom up to the top, and CurlDown looks like the view is being unrolled down on top of the screen from top to bottom.  You should at least give them a look, as they are easy to use.