# UIView flip from top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to flip a UIView from top/bottom using UIViewAnimation ? 
Does anyone have any idea about how this can be accomplished?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632480/flipping-uiviews-from-top-bottom

Comment: i need uiviewanimation not catransition or layer animations.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
[UIView transitionFromView:ViewA toView:ViewB
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                    completion:NULL];
```