# UIView vertical flip animation

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I have an iOS UIView with `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight`. I need it to flip vertically though. The page curl transition won't cut it. I assume this will require something custom.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As of iOS 5.0, there's no need to write your own Core Animation transformation to do vertical flips. Just use UIKit's [`UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop` and `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW105) transitions, and all this stuff becomes a single method call.

These behave analagously to `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` and `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` (which have been around since iOS 2.0).

Example usage:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:viewToReplace
                    toView:replacementView
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                completion:nil];
```

The above code will vertically flip the superview of `viewToReplace`. At the halfway point in the animation, at the instant when the superview is perpendicular to the screen and thus invisible, `viewToReplace` gets replaced by `replacementView`.

It's that easy.

Comment: Note: Insert both views in their superview before calling the animation. The "viewToReplace" must be in front of "replacementView". Both views have to be set to hidden=false.

Comment: @Artjom What you claim differs from my experience. This works perfectly fine for me without inserting the `replacementView` into the superview before calling `transitionFromView:...`. Perhaps there's something else not obviously relevant that we're also doing differently leading to the difference in what we observe? Can you provide an example project demonstrating what you've described?

Comment: In my case both views are initialized from nib as class members. But without inserting both in the flipping superview your method does not work.

Comment: just set the views as properties and then insert only one view, flipping handles the replacement afterwards

Answer (score 67):

Just write your own method for the flip using Core Animation Transforms.

```
- (void)verticalFlip{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration delay:someDelay animations:^{
        yourView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    } completion:^{
        // code to be executed when flip is completed
    }];
}
```

Make sure you have the Core Animation libraries/frameworks added and included and also have included `math.h` if you want to use the `M_PI` notation.

**EDIT:**

To have it essentially "change" the view when it's halfway flipped do something like this:

```
- (void)verticalFlip{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration delay:someDelay animations:^{
        yourView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2,1.0,0.0,0.0); //flip halfway
    } completion:^{
        while ([yourView.subviews count] > 0)
            [[yourView.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview]; // remove all subviews
        // Add your new views here 
        [UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration delay:someDelay animations:^{
            yourView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,1.0,0.0,0.0); //finish the flip
        } completion:^{
            // Flip completion code here
        }];
    }];
}
```

This could also work:

```
- (void)verticalFlip{

    // Do the first half of the flip
    [UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration delay:someDelay animations:^{
        yourView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2,1.0,0.0,0.0); //flip halfway
    } completion:^{
        while ([yourView.subviews count] > 0)
            [[yourView.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview]; // remove all subviews
        // Add your new views here 
    }];

    // After a delay equal to the duration+delay of the first half of the flip, complete the flip
    [UIView animateWithDuration:someDuration delay:durationOfFirstAnimation animations:^{
        yourView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,1.0,0.0,0.0); //finish the flip
    } completion:^{
        // Flip completion code here
    }];
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: I've gotten the view to flip but I need someway of showing the "backside" of the view. Is there a way to hide it's sub views halfway though this animation, so it simulates that the view is "empty" on the backside?

Comment: For a 3D transform, you need to do yourView.layer.transform instead of yourView.transform

Comment: The completion block should have a bool.   completion:^(BOOL finished){

Comment: you should also use call + (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion in the code after "EDIT:" mark - options: parameter is missing in the original comment

Comment: you should rotate on 2 * M_PI not to get you view upside-down in the second half of the flip in the seconds code chunk

Comment: I've created similar solution, but also applying perspective while flipping views http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144446/uiview-flip-vertical-animation/7463047#7463047

Comment: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: This is obsolete; `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom`, added in iOS 5.0, is easier to understand than this.

Comment: How can we make it on touch move in ios?

Answer (score 29):

The code from Brenton didn't work for me so I did a little more digging through the apple docs and [found this piece of code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) for an horizontal flip:

```
- (IBAction)toggleMainViews:(id)sender {
    [UIView transitionFromView:(displayingPrimary ? primaryView : secondaryView)
                        toView:(displayingPrimary ? secondaryView : primaryView)
                      duration:1.0
                       options:(displayingPrimary ? 
                                    UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight :
                                    UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft)
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                   if (finished) {
                                       displayingPrimary = !displayingPrimary;
                                   }
                              }
    ];
}
```

You can do a vertical flip by changing the options from `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` to `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom`.

Worked like a charm.

Comment: it's not a vertical flip. it's system provided horizontal flip

Comment: What's with the downvotes? This code is shorter and clearer than the other examples. Is there a hidden gotcha?

Comment: Someone must have down voted it b/c the original question was about a vertical flip, not a horizontal one. The horizontal ones are easier b/c of the UIViewAnimationOptionTransition constants that Apple provides. Hence, the questioner's original query about a vertical transition effect.

Comment: You can do a vertical flip by changing the options from
`....options:isDetailTileView ? 
         UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight :
         UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft)`

to
`....options:isDetailTileView ? 
     UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop :
     UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom)`

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Much better to use built-in stuff than re-inventing the wheel. Cheers.

Comment: One more thing. If you try to flip subviews and you don't want the superview to flip. Put your two subviews inside a container view. Then it will not flip your fullscreen view!

Comment: -1 for being a horizontal flip, when a vertical one was desired. The question asker already told you in the question that he knew how to use `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight`; this is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Can we make it based on TouchMove event in ios?

Comment: @Cœur well, sure... but in doing so you've essentially made it a duplicate of my answer from 5 years earlier, so it's still adding no value that I can see.

Answer (score 8):

UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop is easy to use, but we can not create an interactive transition using UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop. We need change layer’s transform to create an interactive transition.

Just create a transform using CATransform3DMakeRotation is not enough, no light effect, no perspective. I write an sample to add these effect. You can change it to an interactive transition easily.

Demo:

[image: Flip effect]

Sample code:

```
CALayer *sideALayer = sideAView.layer;
CALayer *sideBLayer = sideBView.layer;
CALayer *containerLayer = containerView.layer;

sideALayer.opacity = 1;
sideBLayer.opacity = 0;
sideBLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0);
containerLayer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;

CATransform3D perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspectiveTransform.m34 = -1.0 / containerViewWidth;
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        sideALayer.opacity = 0;
        containerLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(perspectiveTransform,CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0));
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        sideBLayer.opacity = 1;
        containerLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(perspectiveTransform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0));
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

sideAView and sideBView are subviews of containerView.

The containerView is set a black background.

Comment: There is something wrong with this animation. As you can see, in second half of rotation the perspective is completely removed and it looks weird.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.0 Version** 100% Working Solution

```
// view1: represents view which should be hidden and from which we are starting
// view2: represents view which is second view or behind of view1
// isReverse: default if false, but if we need reverse animation we pass true and it
// will Flip from Left

func flipTransition (with view1: UIView, view2: UIView, isReverse: Bool = false) {
    var transitionOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions() // Swift 4.2
    transitionOptions = isReverse ? [.transitionFlipFromLeft] : [.transitionFlipFromRight] // options for transition
    
    // animation durations are equal so while first will finish, second will start
    // below example could be done also using completion block.
    
    UIView.transition(with: view1, duration: 1.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        view1.isHidden = true
    })
    
    UIView.transition(with: view2, duration: 1.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        view2.isHidden = false
    })
}
```

Call of the function:

```
anim.flipTransition(with: viewOne, view2: viewTwo)
anim.flipTransition(with: viewTwo, view2: viewOne, isReverse: true)
```

Best practice will be to create `UIView` extension and hold this function to that extension so it will be accessible to any `UIView` child object. This solution also can be written using completionBlock.

Comment: Thanks @C0mrade, you saved my time.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the darkening of the views that takes place while doing the flipping?

Answer (score 0):

**To flip into UIView:**

```
  -(void) goToSeconVC
 {
  SecondVC *secondVCObj = [[SecondVC alloc] init];
  [UIView beginAnimation: @”View Flip” context: nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
  [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView: self.navigationController.view cache: NO];
  [sef.navigationController pushViewController: seconVCObj animated: YES];
  [UIView commitAnimation];
 }
**To flip into a view controller:**
          viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
         [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
**To flip out of it:**

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of @C0mrade

```
func flipTransition (with view1: UIView, view2: UIView, isReverse: Bool = false) {
    var transitionOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions()
    transitionOptions = isReverse ? [.transitionFlipFromLeft] : [.transitionFlipFromRight]

    UIView.transition(with: view1, duration: 1.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        view1.isHidden = true
    })

    UIView.transition(with: view2, duration: 1.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        view2.isHidden = false
    })
}
```

Comment: I used this code, but it doesn't look smooth. What I expect is that in the middle of animation hiding first view, the will become hidden. Currently it is hidden at the beginning.

Answer (score -3):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
// checks to see if the view is attached
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                       forView:flipLabel
                         cache:YES];

 flipLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];



[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can make any modification which you want while flipping view, Here I have change the background color

Comment: -1 because a) This is a horizontal flip, and b) I don't think this adds anything new that my answer doesn't already offer.