# UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal Vertically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, uikit

Is it possible to hack the `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` to be vertical instead of horizontal?

I would normally use a `CATransition` to do this, but that method requires inserting the view of one `UIViewController` into the other one, which results in it not being released properly.

So, is it possible without adding one as a subview of another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using the accepted answer from: [UIView vertical flip animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392629/uiview-vertical-flip-animation) and presenting the modal view half way through the animation. This will require some modification of that code, but it should be possible to do.