# CoreAnimation Class Error

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am trying to run the code from the answer at the  [UIView vertical flip animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392629/uiview-vertical-flip-animation) question, and I keep getting this error in Xcode:

```
error: Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'CGAffineTransform' (aka 'struct CGAffineTransform') from incompatible type 'CATransform3D' (aka 'struct CATransform3D')
```

and I don't know how to fix it, and it doesn't seem like it should be happening based on what other people are saying about the code working and such.

The error is on the line of

```
myView.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2,1.0,0.0,0.0);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`CATransform3DMakeRotation` returns a `CATransform3D`. But, `UIView.transform` is a `CGAffineTransform`, which is not the same. You could try

```
myview.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(...);
```

`CALayer`'s `transform` *is* of type `CATransform3D`.