# iOS - Flipping animation like iOS 5 banner notifications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, notifications, rotation

I would like create an animation like the iOS 5 banner notifications, but i don't know how!
Any help? I need code and a little explanation!

Comment: Check out GeekGameBoard sample code in the SDK. Shows you how to do that flip around an axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flip can also be accomplished via view transforms.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392629/uiview-vertical-flip-animation) answer gives a good example.

To be able to incorporate elements of the current screen like the notification does will require more manipulation and grabbing the current display bits.