# Custom flip between 2 views, how to mimic the iOS flip?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've implemented a custom flip using CATransform3DMakeRotation (see [UIView vertical flip animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392629/uiview-vertical-flip-animation)). 
It works fine, causing the flip,  the problem is that it is only a simple rotation.

How can I mimic the iOS style flip where the view seems to skew during the flip?

Cheers!!

Comment: May be the link solves u r problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/how-do-i-apply-a-perspective-transform-to-a-uiview .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding perspective.

```
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
```