# Replicate Apple iOS Podcast.app modal view controller from UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, modalviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I would like to replicate the flipping, growing and showing of a modal view controller as seen in Apple iOS Podcast app on iPad. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llp-oi1Tm-Y&t=15m8s

Do I need to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or `UICollectionViewLayout`? 
Should I use UIView animation block when the user tap the cell?
And where and when should I call `UIView transitionFromView:` method?

Thank You.

Comment: Could you give a more specific example of what you want to recreate from the Podcast app? I don't see a flip and grow animation in the current Apple Podcast App when I use it.  Is it shown in this review video? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86Mbv1NLR9s

Comment: You are right. I should have specified that the flipping behavior appear only on iPad. I am editing right now.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Category on UIViewController and overriding the "presentViewControler:animated:" method is your best bet.  There are other solutions, like animating a UICollectionViewCell and other UIView animation options.

I would take a look at this answer:
[Flip, Grow, and Translate Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038156/flip-grow-and-translate-animation)