# Presenting a modal view controller with flip card effect (flip + transform + translate)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

What I'd like to do is somewhat similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038156/flip-grow-and-translate-animation) which reference this [MLB app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIqv3OH9XIU&feature=youtu.be&t=1m12s), except instead of a grid, I use [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) which is based on UIScrollView.

The answers to that question isn't satisfactory. Seems like you shouldn't need to write the entire animation sequence manually.

Is there a way to do this by simply using presentViewController and the built-in flip transition effect?

Answer (score 8):

Swift iOS 8

If you would like to Flip View controller by View controller

```
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

    // assign page view content loader
    let fBSignRegisterViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FBSignRegisterViewController")
        as? FBSignRegisterViewController;

    fBSignRegisterViewController?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal

     self.presentViewController(fBSignRegisterViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, there's a built in method on [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) to handle this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                  duration:0.2
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{ 
                    [fromView removeFromSuperview]; 
                    [containerView addSubview:toView]; }
                completion:NULL];
```

Or alternatively, with [viewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
AboutViewController * vc = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: I did try this. It does the flipping but it doesn't do the growing. How do we accomplish that?

Comment: For growing you'll have to explore Transforms. Create a custom one and set it as the transform on your view/viewController. If transforms are what you end up using, you wouldn't use them in conjunction with the above default transitions, you'd essentially be rolling your own. Animating [view setTransform:myFlipTransform]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a method for UIView called transitionwithView. Check out an example [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=1LcFLAFbBrgC&pg=PA429&lpg=PA429&dq=UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight%20example&source=bl&ots=MNbD5K6yyf&sig=_ki7DBdsFlv2R3n2Gj-s67EE-RY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N-nyUenSJuOZiAKh24DIDg&ved=0CHMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight%20example&f=false).