# Core Animation window flip effect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

Any tutorials or sample code to get the Core Animation window flip effect? I'm using Flipr right now, which uses Core Image to generate the effect but CoreAnimation is much smoother

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike Lee released some code for just this a while back. He called it [LemurFlip](http://www.atomicwang.org/motherfucker/Index/B4E5D81C-A9A0-403C-B7A3-62FEB81DE777.html).

Answer (score 2):

take a look at uli kusterers windowflipper code.
http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm (search for WindowFlipper)

have no experience with it, but it just might work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I added some code on how I do it using Core animation: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372018/widget-flip-behavior-in-core-animation-cocoa/5082979#5082979)