# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl takes up almost entire screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a modal partial curl but it takes up almost the entire screen, which is not what I want.
IF i use storyboards and to it it's the way i want.
How to make it not taking up the whole screen, but something like half of it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've played with, Page Curl only curls enough to show the content on the next page. You can vary the curl by limiting content to the lower half of the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from writing your own animation OpenGL, there is no public way to do this. The only UIViewAnimation styles available are;

```
typedef enum {
   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
   UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
   UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

See [How do I create a custom page curl Core Animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489061/how-do-i-create-a-custom-page-curl-core-animation)

Comment: If you want to curl up the view, OpenGL isn't overkill, it's what you need to use if the only alternative is Core Animation since Core Animation only supports planes. Maybe SceneKit would be easier though.

Comment: If i use storyboards it's only half.

Comment: @Jesper your correct about OpenGL, edited my post. SceneKit looks really interesting, thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: @Jesper Mmmm didn't know about the existence of SceneKit, is it available for iPhone yet though?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scene_kit_editor/Articles/Inspecting3DScene.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012291-CH4-SW1