# How to add a program into Dashboard and implement to turn over a panel In Mac?

Tags: cocoa, mac-dashboard-widget

I found some programs can put into the Dashboard , and most of them have a feature: when click the "i", the panel will turn over and show another panel , How to implement it ? and how to put a program into a Dashboard? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Developing Dashboard Widgets](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/dashboard.html)

[Dashboard Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/Dashboard%5FRef/DashboardRef/DashboardRef.html)

Comment: firstly thank you, I know how to implement dashboard widget , But how to implement this: when click 'i' , the panel will turn over?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pierre's answer, see also [Dashcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/dashcode/), part of Xcode Tools.

Comment: firstly thank you, I know how to implement dashboard widget , But how to implement this: when click 'i' , the panel will turn over?

Comment: ok , because I want to add the feature: when click a button, the panel will turn over to show another view to my cocoa App, I don't want to implement a dashboard program , I just want to get the effect of click a 'i' or other button , just lick a safari plugin:Cosmopod(http://www.cocoamug.com/store/index.php), and How to do , Thank you very much again!

Comment: So you want to flip an NSView subclass? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372018/widget-flip-behavior-in-core-animation-cocoa